# Cannot add uniqueMember with ldapmodify in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, ldif

I cannot add uniqueMembers to a static group (objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames)

According to this [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v54.kldl0/hcsk8b3061.htm):

> Modifying group entries: In order to add a member to a static group, add the user's distinguished name as an additional value for the member or uniqueMember attribute. Following is an example:
>   ldapmodify -h 127.0.0.1 -D "cn=admin" -w xxxx -f modStaticGrp.ldif

Where modStaticGrp.ldif contains:

```
dn: cn=group1, o=Your Company
changetype: modify
add: member
member: cn=jeff, cn=tim, o=Your Company

dn: cn=group2, o=Your Company
changetype: modify
add: uniqueMember
uniqueMember: cn=joe,o=Your Company
```

When I try to add a uniqueMember with ldapmodify with the following ldif file:

```
dn: cn=Private,o=My Company
changetype: modify
add: uniqueMember 
uniqueMember: uid=1234567890,ou=My Company
```

I get the error:

> ldapmodify: wrong attributeType at line 4, entry "cn=Private,o=My Company”

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: What is the objectClass of the entry you're trying to add to?

Comment: objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames

Comment: In the following post, "Dehli" got it working, with same syntax as I'm: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2552566?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: So let's get this straight: the objectClass of 'cn=Private,o=My Company' is `groupOfUniqueNames`?

Answer (score 1):

```
uid=1234567890,ou=My Company
```

A `uniqueMember` value is a complete DN. Judging by the rest of your DNs this should be something like

```
uid=1234567890,o=My Company
```

although I woudl have expected to see something more like this:

```
uid=1234567890,ou=Users,o=My Company
```

actually, depending on exactly how you've designed your DIT. You shouldn't be adding user entries at its top level.

Comment: My misstake, the users are located under ou=People. So the last line should be: uniqueMember: uid=1234567890,ou=People,o=My Company